# Simple way of deriving probability of drawing your own hat

Tags: probability

This is an example from the book Introduction to Probability SECOND EDITION by
Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis which I am self studying.

Example 2.11. The Hat Problem. Suppose that n people throw their hats in a box and then each picks one hat at random. (Each hat can be picked by only one person, and each assignment of hats to persons is equally likely.) What is the expected value of X, the number of people that get back their own hat? For the ith person. we introduce a random variable $X_i$ that takes the value 1 if the person selects his/her own hat. and takes the value $0$ otherwise. Since $P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{n} $ and $P(X_i = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, the mean of $X_i$ is $$ E[ X_i] = 1* \frac{1}{n}+ 0 * \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)=\frac{1}{n}$$

We now have $$ X=X_1+X_2+ ...+X_n$$
So that $$ E[X] = E[X_1] + E[X)_2] + ... + E[X_n] = n*\frac{1}{n}=1 $$

End of Example.
My question is why did they not show $P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{n} $, since to me it was not obvious and I can show it as follows. $$\begin{align}P(X_i = 1) &=P(\text{ith person picks his hat})*P(\text{first i-1 people do not pick his hat})\\&=\frac{1}{n-(i-1)}*\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}...\frac{n-(i-1)}{n-(i-2)}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n-(i-1)}\frac{n-(i-1)}{n}\\ &= \frac{1}{n} \end{align}\\ $$

So is there a quick explanation why $ P(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$ that avoids going through this derivation?

Comment: I recommend not using gender-specific pronouns to refer to generic hypothetical people. There are enough forces and biases pushing women away from mathematics; it helps if we don't contribute to that.

Comment: In the end, all $n$ hats have been shuffled to one of the $n!$ possible permutations. In a fraction of $1/n$ of those, the $i$-th hat will have been shuffled to the $i$-th position by symmetry of the setup, since there will be equally many permutations having the $i$-th hat in the $k$-th position for any $k=1,2,...,n$.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the example, but I do not quite get what you mean by "by symmetry" and I think an explanation of this would answer my question. Could you elaborate? Why is the probability of drawing a red ball on the second draw equal to $1/6 $ by symmentry?

Comment: Symmetry is either 'obvious' or you can do this: Call red balls A, B, C, D and green balls Y, Z. Then make a list of 30 sample points $\{AB, BA, AC, CA, \dots, YZ, ZY\}.$ There are just as many possibilities with red second as with red first. // For the hats it doesn't matter whether I draw a hat first, second, or last, I still have the same chance of getting my own.

Comment: Trying to fix typos, system balky: Suppose an urn has 4 red balls and 2 green balls. You draw 2 balls without replacement. The probability you get a red ball on the first draw is 4/6 = 2/3. By symmetry, the probability you get a red ball on the second draw (unconditionally) is also 2/3. Depending on your viewpoint, either that is obvious, or you can compute it as $P(R_2)=P(R_1R_2)+P(G_1R_2)=⋯=2/3.$ Your question is not exactly the same, but the issue whether it is obvious or needs to be proved depending on point of view is the same.

Comment: Suppose all persons grab their hat out of the box at exactly the same moment. Can you think of any reason that person $1$ has smaller/larger probability to get his own hat than person $2$? Why should this be different if they are more patient and polite? And "the same moment"... Well of course if we measure in miniseconds there will be an order in that case too. Actually there is no essential difference.

Comment: @drhab: I guess technically it's impossible to grab all hats at the same moment. But however you slice it, one of the hats is mine and under any interpretation of 'random' I have probability $1/n$ of getting that one hat.

Comment: @BruceET I hope it will stimulate the intuition of the OP. Yes, technically impossible, but it can be looked at as selecting an permutation out of $S_n$ where all permutations have equal chances to be elected. Astonishing how many students have difficulties on this subject. In earlier days I was one of them. This until it once ended with the exclamation: "Ahh,...but of course!!.." :-)

Comment: For which of the other hats do you have bigger or smaller chance of ending up with than your own? Mary's? Susan's? Joe's? ....